# having problem with squidGuard. Need help

Tags: firewall, squid

when i write down this command on my terminal for configuring squidguard `squidGuard -d`  this error shows up  `squidGuard: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-4.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please register an account on Ask Ubuntu. It helps to prevent you from losing access to your other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type as

```
sudo apt-get install libdb-4.6.so
```

Then restart your system to apply the changes then try again to launch it.

Comment: ok.let me work on this and ill let you know.just wait ok

Comment: sir no positive outcome. it gives some other error

Comment: hassaan@hassaan-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ sudo apt-get install libdb-4.6.so
[sudo] password for hassaan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libdb-4.6.so
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libdb-4.6.so'